# How to save a high resolution image with magick in R?

Tags: r, imagemagick

I would like to create a high resolution “montage” of 3 by 3 using the `magick` package.

```r
library(magick)
#> Linking to ImageMagick 6.9.7.4
#> Enabled features: fontconfig, freetype, fftw, lcms, pango, x11
#> Disabled features: cairo, ghostscript, rsvg, webp

# Read the image and resize it
frink <- image_read("https://jeroen.github.io/images/frink.png")
frink <- image_resize(frink, "100x")

# Create 1 column with 3 rows
col <- image_append(rep(frink, 3), stack = TRUE)

# "Combine" 3 columns
i <- image_append(c(col, col, col))

i
```

[image]

So my question is how can I save it to a high-resolution png (e.g., 300 DPI)? I was thinking to use `image_write()`, but apparently I can not set the resolution I want there.

```r
# This is not working
# image_write(i, tempfile(), res = 300)
```

Thank you,
Phil

<sup>Created on 2019-05-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Perhaps just set the density before writing to output. See https://rmagick.github.io/imageattrs.html#density

Comment: I am not sure how. I have tried `image_read("path", density = 600)` but no luck. Also from the documentation: "resolution to render **pdf or svg**". So it seems it is not for raster image.

Comment: Density only controls how a raster image will be printed. It does not affect the quality of the raster image itself. To get a higher quality raster you will need to start with a higher quality raster png (created larger in width and height -- you cannot just resize it to be larger).

Comment: did you manage to do it ? I am looking to do the same operation with the `magick` package ...

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem but found the solution in the magick vignett https://docs.ropensci.org/magick/articles/intro.html#read-and-write

```
image_write(i, path = "final.png", format = "png")
```

Comment: And if you want to change the DPI, add `density = 300`.