# Create multi-panel figure using PNG/JPEG images

Tags: r, image, ggplot2, png, jpeg

**Problem:**

I want to make a multi-panel figure using PNG or JPEG images. The images were not created in R but I want to patch them together in R to form one figure. All the images are the same size/dimensions.

**What I've tried:**

```
library(png)

img1 <- readPNG("filepath/img1.png")
img2 <- readPNG("filepath/img2.png")

library(patchwork)

patch <- img1 + img2
patch
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 3 matrix slice(s) ]
```

I increased the max print multiple times (to ridiculously high numbers):

```
options(maxprint = 1000000000000)
```

But still get the same error.

I then tried making each image into a ggplot (without the points) using:

```
library(ggplot2)

img1plot <- ggplot() + 
background_image(img1) +
theme(plot.margin = margin(t=1, l=1, r=1, b=1, unit = "cm"))
```

Which returns the following error:

```
Error in background_image(d311) : 
  could not find function "background_image"
```

Is there another way to patch images together in R to make a figure?

**Edit:**

Based on the comment from @davidnortes, I tried the following:

```
p1 <- ggplot2::annotation_custom(grid::rasterGrob(img1,
                                            width=ggplot2::unit(1,"npc"),
                                            height=ggplot2::unit(1,"npc")),
                           -Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf)

p2 <- ggplot2::annotation_custom(grid::rasterGrob(img2,
                                                  width=ggplot2::unit(1,"npc"),
                                                  height=ggplot2::unit(1,"npc")),
                               -Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf)


library(cowplot)

plots <- plot_grid(
  p1, p2,
  labels = c('A', 'B'),
  align="hv"
)
plots
```

I get the following warning messages and the plot doesn't form:

```
Warning messages:
1: In as_grob.default(plot) :
  Cannot convert object of class LayerInstanceLayerggprotogg into a grob.
2: In as_grob.default(plot) :
  Cannot convert object of class LayerInstanceLayerggprotogg into a grob.
```

Comment: Sorry man! there was a bug in my answer with ggplot2; that's why you got the errors.  I'm editing it now

Comment: Your first attempt would've **almost** worked, BTW. With `library(patchwork)` you can do `patch <- wrap_elements(img1) + wrap_elements(img2)`. You can't directly view it, but `ggsave` works fine. Also, make sure to set `native = TRUE` in the `readPNG`.

Comment: Thanks for adding this @mths !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm giving you the couple of alternatives that I Use the most:

**Alternative 1**: combination of **ggplot2, grid and cowplot**.

Each of your PNG image can be embedded in a ggplot object using:

```
ggplot2::ggplot() + ggplot2::annotation_custom(grid::rasterGrob(YourPNGimage,
                                                width=ggplot2::unit(1,"npc"),
                                                height=ggplot2::unit(1,"npc")),
                               -Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf)
```

Then you can use `cowplot::plot_grid()` to arrange your plots.

**Alternative 2:** using **magick** package.

The package counts on its own functions to read images, thus we need to tweak your code a bit:

```
img1 <- magick::image_read("filepath/img1.png")
img2 <- magick::image_read("filepath/img2.png")
```

Then using functions like `magick::image_append(c(img1, img2))` you can combine them. See the [magick package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html#preview) for more info.

Comment: Thank you, the second option using magick worked! However, the resolution is quite low (96 dpi). Is there a way to specify resolution (e.g. 300 dpi) like in ggsave?

Comment: In `magick::image_write` you have parameters like `density` and `quality` that help to to specify output qualities. Though it is possible that you cannot make high resolution renders from low resolution PNGs. The quality of the input is going to setup the quality of the output; Let's see if someone knows better  than me on such regard :)

Comment: @jl748795 have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56060625/how-to-save-a-high-resolution-image-with-magick-in-r

Comment: Thanks @davidnortes! I imported 300 dpi PNG files, so theoretically the file size should be larger than 96 dpi when they are combined. But using "density =" allows me to account for this.

Comment: One more question, is it possible to choose the number of columns using this function? I can only find information on stack = TRUE, which stacks photos vertically instead of horizontally, but I want to have 3 columns

Comment: @jl748795 most likely you are going to have to define as many objects as columns (using _image_append_), then append them altogether

Comment: Sorry, I meant multiple rows and columns (I have 7 photos total), which I don't think is possible based on my searches, so I may need to find another solution

Comment: I did not explain myself then. I meant that, as a workaround,  you can create, for example, your rows using *image_append()* storing them as magick image objects. Then you stack those objects with *image_append(c(row1,row2,...,row n), stack = TRUE)*

Comment: @davidnortes, when I convert the png image to a ggplot object it results in loss of quality? is there a better way to read multiple  png images and use the `wrap_images` function in patchwork to maintain high quality images ? My answer below results in high quality image, but adding text annotation such as subheads within a collage is complicated with magick. Thought converting to ggplot gives a better control . Any suggestions regarding this ?

Comment: I've looking around and I got to tell you that, sadly, I have no answer for you (yet)

Answer (score 2):

You can also `rbind` image arrays. But as they are 3D (x,y,RGB) you must use `abind` function from `abind` package. along=1 to bind vertically, 2 horizontally.

Works because image have same size.

```
img1 <- readPNG("filepath/img1.png")
img2 <- readPNG("filepath/img2.png")
img12 <- abind::abind(img1,img2,along=1)
png::writePNG(img12,"filepath/img12.png")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use magick package in R to do a collage.

```
# read the the png files into a list
  pngfiles <-
  list.files(
    path = here::here("png_ouput_folder"),
    recursive = TRUE,
    pattern = "\\.png$",
    full.names = T
  )
 
 # read images and then create a montage
 # tile =2 , means arrange the images in 2 columns
 # geometry controls the pixel sixe, spacing between each image in the collage output. 

 magick::image_read(pngfiles) %>%
      magick::image_montage(tile = "2", geometry = "x500+10+5") %>%
      magick::image_convert("jpg") %>%
      magick::image_write(
        format = ".jpg", path = here::here(paste(name,"_collage.jpg",sep="")),
        quality = 100
      )
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As others have suggested the **magick** package is much simpler than a low-level solutions using grobs and related. **magick** is powerful but IMHO the documentation is poor and very circular.

However, there is a simple solution to your question in the page for `image_montage()`. The most important argument is the `geometry` specification, which governs the spacing between the "tiles."

```r
library(magick)
input <- rep(logo, 12)
image_montage(input, geometry = 'x100+10+10', tile = '4x3', bg = 'pink', shadow = TRUE)
```

To get no spacing at all, use `geometry = '0x100+0+0', shadow = FALSE"`.